# adjacency model , given an id return the leaf nodes

Tags: mysql

This is the table for storing a categories/subcategories site navigation :

```
   $query = "CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    parentid int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)"  ;
```

And say these are the entries inside the table

```
id  name    parentid
1   animal  NULL
2   vegetable NULL
3   mineral NULL
4   doggie  1
5   kittie  1
6   horsie  1
7   gerbil  1
8   birdie  1
9   carrot  2
10  tomato  2
11  potato  2
12  celery  2
13  rutabaga    2
14  quartz  3
```

What I want is such an sql query that for a given id , all the leaf nodes are returned AND if the id of a leaf node is given then the leaf node is itself returned.

So if the id 2 is set , the rows returned are - carrot,tomato,potato,celery,rutabaga.
If the id is 9 is given , the row returned is - 9 itself

Possible?

my subcategoires won't go more than 3 levels deep.

I tried the code given [on this page](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) , but it doesn't give the leaf node , if the leaf node id is given.

Thanks

I tried a few queries..

```
    SELECT distinct t1.name FROM
categories AS t1 LEFT JOIN categories as t2
ON t1.id = t2.parent
 LEFT JOIN categories as t3
ON t2.id = t3.parent
WHERE  t1.parent = ? OR t1.id = ?
```

but I am simply not able to understand joins.

Edit: I can forgo the return leaf node, if leaf node id given part . Now I just need a query that will return all leaf nodes , given a category/subcategory node. Thanks again

Comment: what is the query u try till now

Comment: You'll make your life a lot easier if you move away from an adjacency list and use either nested sets or a closure table... see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/192462/623041).

Comment: I agree with eggyval: as MySQL (still) does not support recursive queries, using an adjancency model is not a good fit for MySQL

Comment: i think you need to split tables otherwise try my code for your querry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the final query that I use looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct t2.id , t2.name FROM
    categories AS t1 LEFT JOIN categories as t2
    ON t1.id = t2.parent
     LEFT JOIN categories as t3
    ON t2.id = t3.parent
    WHERE  t1.parent = $id OR t1.id = $id and t2.visible = 1
```

if an empty result set is returned, it means an ending node was supplied and I simply return the supplied $id.
its working. Hopefully it will continue to do so, because I am kind of guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
select * from `categories` where id=something and parentid is not null 
union all
select * from `categories` where parentid=something;
```

And tell me if it works (replace something with the desired value).